# Rich edit in place

Tags: php, javascript, html, richtextediting, edit-in-place

What is the best solution for something that support:

- rich editor
- edit in place
- placeholder
- save HTML and strip out malicious  etc.

I would like to have a nice and usable interface to change data on a profile.
It must support bold, italic and multi-line text and being sure that no malicious code can be injected.

I am looking mostly for the Javascript side but if it come with some PHP code for the backend, it would be nice.

Comment: TinyMCE is nice a rich editor. CKEditor is even nicer but it is not free.

Comment: For what I know they do not have built in edit-in-place, place holder. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

FCK Editor which is now [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

[it is free.](http://ckeditor.com/license)

Comment: See comment on the questions.

Answer (score 1):

I use TinyMCE (http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).  It should have the majority of the functionality you need.

Comment: See comment on the questions.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a few options:

- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (my personal favorite)
- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) (also very popular)
- [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/)
- [YUI's Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/editor/) (part of much larger, and very good, YUI framework)
- [Google's Closure Editor](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/editor.html) (part of Google's closure framework, what you get in GMail etc.)
- [Dijit Editor](http://jaredj.dojotoolkit.org/demo/) (if you're using the Dojo framework)
- [OpenWYSIWYG](http://www.openwebware.com/) (true open source)
- [jwysiwyg](http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/) (for jQuery)

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor
and http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/07/rounding-up-the-best-javascript-wysiwyg-and-markup-editor/

Answer (score 1):

I correctly use [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) but I would have changed to [aloha-editor](http://aloha-editor.com/), an HTML5 WYSIWYG editor, if I had the time.

That said, I would not recommend any of those WYSIWYG editors as the html output is not only poor but also breaks the overall design by introducing a lot of inline styling that you probably did not expect for.

The only reason I use such an editor is that the client strictly asked for one. If you choose to use this method anyway, you would probably have to preprocess the user input. If I have a choice I use Markdown.

[EDIT: Added an example] As you can see in the html output below, what you see in not always what you get...

**WYSIWYG Example:**
[image: WYSIWYG example]

**Markdown Example:**
[image: Markdown example]

Comment: Aloha Editor tries to avoid such bad source code as above. We try to generate clean and transparent xHTML code. Please test. If you find something that produces “bad” code report at https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor. It will be fixed with high priority.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong (and please let me know if i am), but i don't believe TinyMCE nor CKedit do in place editing (that is, they do not use the contenteditable="true" without creating an iframe).

As far as i can tell, only nicedit ( http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=4 ) and google closure ( http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/seamlessfield.html ) are able to edit inline.

I hope i'm wrong :)
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

EDIT:
And @wajiw beat me to it. Good sign though. :)

Comment: See comment on the questions.